# ASP.NET flash / TempData memory

Tags: asp.net

in some frameworks there is a kind of session variables called flash (like in Ruby On Rails) that allows to store variables globally (like a Session Object) but only for the consecutive call (just like TempData in ASP.NET MVC).

Any way to do this is ASP.NET webforms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there is not in ASP.NET you should implement it manually, just keep in session in first steep and delete in last